# Transform.parent is not working to access the grandparent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to find the rigidbody2D assigned to the grandparent of the object that the script is assigned to,but Transform.parent.parent is not working to do this,

`transform.parent.parent.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Rigidbody2D parent);`

this is my code, but it won't get the rigidbody, there is one there because if I set the variable to be public I can assign it in the editor manually, but that won't work in this case for the game, is there any other way to access the grandparent object?

Answer (score 1):

Instead rather simply use [`GetComponentInParent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentInParent.html)

> Returns the component of Type type in the `GameObject` or any of its parents.

(**Since version 2021**) Optionally pass in `true` to include inactive objects and disabled components

```
var rb = GetComponentInParent<Rigidbody2D>(true);
if(rb)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Grandparent object is the top item in the hierarchy then you can use `transform.root` to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
    RigidBody2D rb = transform.parent.GetComponentInParent<RigidBody2D>();
    if(rb)
    {
        //do Something
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.